# Keep a diary, take a diary, write a diary?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, differences

What is the appropriate verb for the word "diary," if I want to express the process of recording personal experiences every day? (Maybe not in an actually book but typing them in a computer.)

Merriam-Webster [suggests](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/diary) me to use "keep a diary". But when I searched the phrases with Google, there were about 700,000 results for "keep a diary," about 1.6 million results for "take a diary," and about 1.2 million results for "write a diary." Which one is more correct? Or are they actually interchangeable? Or are they all correct but they have different meanings?

Comment: 'Take a diary' is hardly related to the others; compare 'lose a diary'.

Comment: Those Google search results also include cases where someone misspelled "dairy."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem here is that the number of hits Google says you have is [wrong](https://searchengineland.com/why-google-cant-count-results-properly-53559).

Using the right tool will give a more accurate picture. I searched [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) for `_v* a diary`, which finds a verb followed by "a diary". There I get:

- ~212 results for "keep* a diary" (where "keep" includes "kept", "keeping", etc.). Some dictionaries ([such as this one](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/keep)) explicitly list this sense of "keep". It's really no different than "keeping records".
- ~15 results for "write* a diary" (again, this includes other forms of "write").
- no hits for "take a diary", although I could see it being used if you meant "remove": "take a diary from the pile".

### The winner is: *keep* a diary.

Comment: Maybe you could add additional information for why *keep* is used. My suspicion is because it's typically a daily or regular occurrence and so the diary is "kept" up to date. Just a guess though.

Comment: Google ngrams (based on usage in their corpus of books) corroborates this, with "keep a diary" having a frequency nine times that of "write a diary", and the occurrence of the phrase "take a diary" negligible in comparison. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=keep+a+diary%2Ctake+a+diary%2Cwrite+a+diary&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckeep%20a%20diary%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20a%20diary%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwrite%20a%20diary%3B%2Cc0

Comment: You have to be very careful with raw Google results. Look at actual hits to see what's going on. For "take a diary", I see very quickly: "**Take a diary** and start writing." "Lots of things can affect the way you feel, from the weather to the medicines you **take. A diary** can help you track ...". "**Take a diary** and a pen wherever you go." "What a unique and interesting concept: **take a diary** of a 15 year old boy and write a virtual living history book around it!" In none of these cases is "take a diary" used to convey the general notion of having and regularly writing in a diary.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, that's basically what I was saying. I think adding that to the answer helps distinguish that *keep* in this sense includes more than simply maintaining possession of something, which is why it's more appropriate than "write".